# "Hidden content" in a question

Tags: bug, editing

I recently noticed this question: [Symmetric Group $S_n$ is generated by transpositions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3396086) (Here is link to the [revision at the time](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3396086/3).)

This question looked that way:

> I have to proof, that a symmetric group 
>   S
>   n
>   , with n>=2 with support {a1, a2, ... , ap} such that σ(ak)= ak+1 (when k
>
> I started by verifying that σ(1) • (1,2) • σ(2) = (2,3) Transposition. Then by iteration I show that the next Transposition (3,4) = σ(1) • (2,3) • σ(2)... Iterating until Transposition (n,1). after this how can I then proof that 
>   S
>   n
>    is generated by this Transposition?
>
> Thanks!

Note the unfinished sentence at the end of the first paragraph.

However, when I clicked the "edit" button, the end of the first paragraph was there. Why is it not displayed?

Comment: I guess it's because the `<` is interpreted as an open HTML tag. Not sure why it's not a problem when the question is in edit mode. One way to fix it is to replace the `<` with an HTML code: `&lt;`. Of course, LaTeX would be preferable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you have `k<p` the parser breaks down and omits the remainder of the paragraph.

This is one of the main reasons why it is important to properly format questions like this with $\rm\LaTeX$.

Comment: I'm not sure about the downvote. Is this disagreement? With what? With the explanation of the behavior, with the behavior itself, or with the suggestion that proper formatting is important in more ways than one?

Comment: Maybe someone wants you to recommend MathJax, not LaTeX.

Comment: Or maybe someone thinks the parser shouldn't break down.

Comment: maybe somebody has watched tom scott's video about the self retweeting tweet, and thinks that if the parser can't escape the character, somebody could use a script tag to do remote javascript execution.

Comment: The obligatory link to an XKCD comic is [here](https://xkcd.com/327/).